# Mongo db aggregation - $push and $slice top results

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aws-documentdb

I have the following documents in my db:

```
{uid: 1, score: 10}
{uid: 2, score: 11}
{uid: 3, score: 1}
{uid: 4, score: 6}
{uid: 5, score: 2}
{uid: 6, score: 3}
{uid: 7, score: 8}
{uid: 8, score: 10}
```

I want to split them into buckets by score - i.e.:

| score | uids | (bucket name in aggregation) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `[0,4)` | 3,5,6 | 0 |
| `[4,7)` | 4 | 4 |
| `[7,inf` | 1,2,7,8 | 7 |

For this, I created the following aggregation which works just fine:

```
db.scores.aggregation(
    [
        {
            $bucket: 
                {
                    groupBy: "$score",
                    boundaries: [0, 4, 7],
                    default: 7,
                    output:
                        {
                            "total": {$sum: 1},
                            "top_frustrated": 
                                {
                                    $push: {
                                        "uid": "$uid", "score": "$score"
                                    }
                                },
                        },
                }
        },
    ]
)
```

However, I would like to return only the top 3 of every bucket - i.e, buckets 0, 4 should be the same, but bucket 7 should have only uids 1,2,8 returned (as uid 7 has the lowest score) - but to include the total count of documents as well, i.e. output of bucket "7" should look like:

```
{ "total" : 4, "top_scores" : 
    [
        {"uid" : 2, "score" : 11},
        {"uid" : 1, "score" : 10},
        {"uid" : 8, "score" : 10},
    ]
}
```

I tried using [$addFields](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) with [$sortArray](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sortArray/) and [$slice](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/), but it either won't work or return errors.

I can of course use `$project` but I was wondering if there is a more efficient way.

I am using Amazon DocumentDB.

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: the last part was cut off, I re-wrote it. Thanks

Comment: What is your mongodb version?

Comment: I am using Amazon DocumentDB, but anything that works for PyMongo 4.1.1 will do

Comment: There is a way, but I am not sure whether it will work for you.

Comment: can you please provide more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$topN` accumulator, instead of `$push`, like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$bucket": {
      "groupBy": "$score",
      "boundaries": [
        0,
        4,
        7
      ],
      "default": 7,
      "output": {
        "total": {
          "$sum": 1
        },
        "top_frustrated": {
          "$topN": {
            "n": 3,
            "sortBy": {
              "score": -1
            },
            "output": {
              "uid": "$uid",
              "score": "$score"
            }
          }
        }
      },  
    }
  },
])
```

Playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0Hyd5PAy9xZ).

The only catch here is this operator is present in MongoDB 5.2 and above.

For older versions, this will work:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$sort": {
      score: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $bucket: {
      groupBy: "$score",
      boundaries: [
        0,
        4,
        7
      ],
      default: 7,
      output: {
        "total": {
          $sum: 1
        },
        "top_frustrated": {
          $push: {
            "uid": "$uid",
            "score": "$score"
          }
        },
        
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      total: 1,
      top_frustrated: {
        "$slice": [
          "$top_frustrated",
          3
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/P9hj73rW916).

Comment: unfortunately Amazon DocumentDB is currently compatible only with MongoDB 3.6 and 4.0 APIs

Comment: That's why I said it may not work for you. You will need an extra stage to sort and slice the arrays

Comment: Any idea how to do that?

Comment: yeah, so as I said in my question - I was wondering if there is a more efficient way than $project. But I guess this should work as there are only three buckets... But, note that the  $slice won't return the top 3 by score, but the first 3 returned from the $bucket aggregation

Comment: $slice will return the top 3 by score only, because I am sorting by score, before grouping them into buckets. The buckets itself will be sorted by score. Otherwise you will have to unwind and sort the buckets, then group them Which is much less effifcient

Comment: I didn't see you sorted before - this indeed should do the trick. I did `{"$addFields": {"top_frustrated": {"$slice": ["$top_frustrated", 3]}}},` instead of the `$project` stage, no idea if this more or less efficient.

Comment: doesn't matter much here because, we are just overriding an already existing field and it is the last stage as well